# PDOException not being caught

Tags: php, pdo

I'm working on a simple login with mysql using pdo. Everything works fine so now I'm focusing on the error handling. But there's a problem. In my `dbconfig` I voluntarily saved the wrong `psw/email/dbname` to create an error.

```
<?php
session_start();
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'Captive');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'arancione');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'geochimie');
function get_db() {
    $dbhost=DB_SERVER;
    $dbuser=DB_USERNAME;
    $dbpass=DB_PASSWORD;
    $dbname=DB_DATABASE;
    try {
        $dbConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
        $dbConnection->exec("set names utf8");
        $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $dbConnection;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        header("../pages/errore.php?errore=dbconfig");
    }
}
?>
```

However, no error can be caught so when I prepare a statement using the db connection returned by `get_db()` I get this:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Here is the php script where I prepare the stmt:

```
<?php 
class Admin {
    public function userLogin( $email,$password)
    {
        try{
            $db = get_db();
            $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM admin WHERE email=:email AND psw=:hash_password');
            $stmt->bindParam("email", $email,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
            $stmt->bindParam("hash_password", $password,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
            $stmt->execute();
            $count=$stmt->rowCount();
            $data=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $db = null;
            if($count)
            {
                $_SESSION['uid']=$data->id;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            header("Location: ../pages/errore.php?errore=db");
        }


    }
}
?>
```

As you can see there is another try-catch but It doesn't work at the same way. Many thanks for your attention!

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null is not a PDOException

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, It seems that I needed to add die() or exit() after the header in the catch blocks. Now I can handle the errors properly.

Comment: Yes, header relocations should always be followed by `die` or `exit`.